# log4J to log files per thread, but not able to release loggers even when the thread dies

Tags: logging, log4j

**strong text**I have called getLogger(Unique Identifier ) to create single logger per thread and generated different files based on the thread Id and other unique identifiers using log4j.

I generage multiple log files for each request sent to my application, Now even when the thread of requests are executed, ie the thread dies, I am not able to delete the log file associated with that thread.

if i try to use logger.shutdown(), it shuts other open threads loggers as well which halts the logging in other files.

Please suggest a solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Log4j's file lock life cycle isn't related to thread life cycle.

If you can catch thread dying timing...

```
Logger log = Logger.gerLogger(yourCategoryName);
Enumeration<?> enumeration = log.getAllAppenders();
while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
    ((Appender) enumeration.nextElement()).close();
}
```

*Caution* It's can't recovery your "Appender".